# apply strsplit to specific column in a data.frame 

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe with classification information. Here is an example:

```
> d <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), classification = c("cl1.scl1", "cl2", "cl3-bla", "cl4.subclass2"))
> d
  x classification
1 1       cl1.scl1
2 2            cl2
3 3        cl3-bla
4 4  cl4.subclass2
```

Before I do any further processing I need to aggregate the classification information, which means that I have to split the classification strings by "." and take the first token. This is the result I need:

```
> d
  x classification
1 1            cl1
2 2            cl2
3 3        cl3-bla
4 4            cl4
```

At the moment I am computing this as follows:

```
d$classification = unlist(lapply(d$classification, function (x) strsplit(as.character(x), ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]))
```

This works, but it took me quite a while to figure this out. I assume there is a more elegant solution, which I probably missed. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Your subject title is a bit misleading; this isn't really about applying a function to a specific column, but how to manipulate the results from strsplit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with back-references.

```
gsub("(.*)\\.(.*)","\\1",d$classification)
```

There are 2 references (the portions of the regular expression in parenthesis), separated by a literal period.  We replace whatever matches that pattern with the contents of the first reference.

Comment: Thanks for that, great solution! Didn't know that I can simply apply regex on data frames.

Comment: Technically, you're applying the regular expression to a character vector (`d$classification` is not a data.frame).

Answer (score 15):

A slightly shorter solution is

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(d$class), "\\."), `[`, 1)
```

Comment: great answer.. `\`[\`` is new to me though, could you give some background or documentation for it?

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the stuff that follows the "."

```
> sub("\\..+$", "", d$class)
[1] "cl1"     "cl2"     "cl3-bla" "cl4"  

d$classification <-  sub("\\..+$", "", d$classification)
 # I've never been very comfortable with partial name matching.
```