# How to access variable length lists inside a list in R

Tags: r

When I call strsplit() on a column of a data frame, depending on the results of the strsplit(), I sometimes get one or two "sublists" as a result of splitting. For example,

```
v <- c("50", "1 h 30 ", "1 h", NA)
split <- strsplit(v, "h")
[[1]]
[1] "50"

[[2]]
[1] "1"   " 30"

[[3]]
[1] "1 "

[[4]]
[1] NA
```

I know I can access the individual lists of split using '[]' and '[[]]' tells me the contents of those sublists, so I think I understand that. And that I can access the " 30" in [[2]] by doing split[[2]][2].

Unfortunately, I don't know how to access this programmatically over the entire column that I have. I am trying to convert the column to numeric data. But that "1 h 30" case is giving me a lot of trouble.

```
func1 <- function(x){
  split.l <- strsplit(x, "h")
  len <- lapply(split.l, length)
  total <- ifelse(len == 2, as.numeric(split.l[2]) + as.numeric(split.l[1]) * 60, as.numeric(split.l[2])) 
  return(total)
}

v <- ifelse(grepl("h", v), func1(v), as.numeric(v))
```

I know len returns the vector of the length of the splits. But when it comes to actually accessing that individual sublist's second element, I simply don't know how to do it properly. This will generate an error because split.l[1] and split.l[2] will only return the first two elements of the entire original dataframe column every time. [[1]] and [[2]] won't work either. I need something like [[i]][1] and [[i]][2]. But I'm trying not to use a for loop and iterate.

To make a long story short, how do I access the inner list element programmatically

For reference, I did look at this which helped. But I still haven't been able to solve it. [apply strsplit to specific column in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748149/apply-strsplit-to-specific-column-in-a-data-frame)

I'm really struggling with lists and list processing in R so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom is `lapply(l,`[`, 2)`, which applied to your example gives:

```
> lapply(split, `[`, 2)
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] " 30 "

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] NA
```

`sapply()` will collapse this to a vector if it can.

What is being done is `lapply()` takes each component of `split` in turn — this is the `[[i]]` bit of your pseudo code — and to each of those we want to extract the `n`th element. We do by applying the `[` function with argument `n`— in this case `2L`.

If you want the first element unless there is a second element, in which case take the second, you could just write a wrapper instead of using `[` directly:

```
wrapper <- function(x) {
    if(length(x) > 1L) {
        x[2L]
    } else {
        x[1L]
    }
}

lapply(split, wrapper)
```

which gives

```
> lapply(split, wrapper)
[[1]]
[1] "50"

[[2]]
[1] " 30 "

[[3]]
[1] "1 "

[[4]]
[1] NA
```

or perhaps

```
lens <- lengths(split)
out <- lapply(split, `[`, 2L)
ind <- lens == 1L
out[ind] <- lapply(split[ind], `[`, 1L)
out
```

but that loops over the output from `strsplit()` twice.