# How to apply strsplit to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748149/apply-strsplit-to-specific-column-in-a-data-frame), but I have a more complicated situation.

Here is my sample code:

```
test = data.frame(x = c(1:4), 
                 y = c("/abc/werts/h1-1234", "/abc/fghye/seths/h2-234",
                           "/abc/gvawrttd/hyeadar/h3-9868", "/abc/qqras/x1-7653"))
test$y = as.character(test$y)
```

And I want an output like this:

```
1 h1-1234
2 h2-234
3 h3-9868
4 x1-7653
```

I tried:

```
test$y = tail(unlist(strsplit(test$y, "/")), 1)
```

However, the result of above codes returned:

```
1 h1-1234
2 h1-1234
3 h1-1234
4 h1-1234
```

So my question is, how should modified my code so that I can get my desired output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the line you are looking for:

```
test$y = sapply(strsplit(test$y, "/"), tail, 1)
```

It applies `tail` to each element in the list returned by `strsplit`.

Comment: You made my task easy with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `sub` to match zero or more characters (`.*`) followed by `/` (`\\/`) followed by zero or more characters that are not a `/` captured as a group (`([^/]*)`) until the end (`$`) of the string, and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the capture group

```
test$y <- sub(".*\\/([^/]*)$", "\\1", test$y)
test$y
#[1] "h1-1234" "h2-234"  "h3-9868" "x1-7653"
```